# Set both ipv4 and ipv6 for confd netconf ssh connection

Tags: ssh, confd, netconf

I am using confd version 6.3. I'm trying to set it up to be able to ssh with netconf over ipv4 and ipv6. My related configuration looks as follows:

```
  <netconf>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <transport>
      <ssh>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <ip>::</ip>
        <port>2022</port>
      </ssh>

      <!-- NETCONF over TCP is not standardized, but it can be useful
           during development in order to use e.g. netcat for scripting.
      -->
      <tcp>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <ip>127.0.0.1</ip>
        <port>2023</port>
      </tcp>
    </transport>
    ....
</netconf>
```

Which result in

```
root@0eeefd5ae80c:/shared# netstat -ln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
...
tcp6       0      0 :::2022                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

When I change ip to 0.0.0.0 then it listens over ipv4. But I am not able to set both ipv4 and ipv6. Is it even possible>

Comment: Haha, nice, I have received a minus, but no comment, and nobody was able to answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that it is possible to use a parameter that is not described in manifest. So in order to do that  can be used:

```
...
  <netconf>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <transport>
      <ssh>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <ip>0.0.0.0</ip>
        <port>2022</port>
        <extraIpPorts>:::830</extraIpPorts>
      </ssh>
  </netconf>
...
```